# Send file as attachment using REST API of DB2 in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, ibm-cloud, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I need to send a file present in azure data lake to IBM cloud server using the REST API of DB2.

I have used the rest API in command prompt in the below format 
curl -X POST "" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer " -k -F fichier=.csv

I have tried to use a Web activity but I was not successful.

I would like to know how this activity can be done in ADF?

Comment: All I know is that you can get data from a REST API using the http connector however according to the documentation there is no direct way of using HTTP connector as a sink, maybe you can create a custom activity and remotely call  powershell/cmd commands (I have not tried this yet)

Answer (score 1):

Bharath, based on your description, I want to provide two suggestions:

1.As @Saul Cruz said in the command, you could use [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/ga-ie/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) to run the command to do the transfer mission.

2.I found Azure Data Factory copy activity has [Azure Data Lake connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store) and [DB2 connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-db2),you could configure copy activity to transfer the csv file.

---

Update Answer:

Per my research, Web activity is not suitable for you. It's unstable for transfer data.

Since you want to avoid custom activity, maybe I suggest you adopt below solution:

1.Use Copy activity to transfer `csv` file from Azure Data Lake to Azure Blob Storage.

2.Use [Azure Function Blob Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to monitor any change feed,then send rest request in function.

Comment: Hi Jay, The DB2 is in a different environment all together and hence I am trying to use a REST API. I am trying to avoid the custom activity as much as possible. Let me know if there is no other way of sending the file. Can you let me know if it can be possible via HTTP connector?

Comment: @BharathRS Hi, my suggestion is mentioned in my update answer.